# Button in IPad SplitView tableViewCell

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4, uibutton

I want to add 3 buttons in the RootViewController for the iPad SplitViewController. I want to display these 3 buttons in a tabular form so that clicking on each I get a separate view in the detailViewController

Comment: Hi, please give more information about your project specifics. Are you using iOS 5 (The new SVC in iOS 5 is much better than 4) and are you using storyboards?

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, but I want to add a segmented control to the DetailViewController of a SplitViewBased iPad App. I want the rootView to remain constant which contains a list of names and want a segmented control on the right side of the screen which is the DetailViewController such that every time the RootView (which on the left) remains the same but the DetailView should change as a segmented control is clicked. Any idea how to do it for iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't given a whole lot of details on this question, I'll assume that this is what you want: [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

Here's an example of what it will look like on an iPhone.  It's basically the same on an iPad:

[image: Segmented Control]
<sub>(source: [episode-2.com](http://blog.episode-2.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/uisegmentedcontrol-3.jpg))</sub>

To add it to a Navigation Bar, use the `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl]` method.  You can then add it like a normal `UIBarButtonItem`.